# How can i eliminate getting junk value through redis get command?

Tags: redis, jedis

**Problem:**

- I am getting junk values like "OK" for redis get call.
- This issue reproduces often over a particular period of time irrespective of the keys trying to obtain through get command.

**I'm Using :**

- Redis version 2.8
- Jedis client 2.5.1 to connect Redis

Please suggest some solution to resolve this issue.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Jedis - upgrade to a newer version (latest is 2.8) or use a different client (Lettuce is my favorite).

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Can you please suggest me a way to reproduce this issue ?

Comment: Sorry, drawing blanks here. I think the best for you would be to contact the Jedis project for debugging/tracing/fixing it: https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues

Comment: Please do consider [1]: https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/397
  [2]: https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/583
  [3]: https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/Getting-started#using-jedis-in-a-multithreaded-environment

Comment: Yeah!! Would do the same Itamar Haber. Can you please suggest some temporary fix for this from my side until the issue with jedis gets fixed ?

Comment: Thanks! @Santhosh Joshi.

Comment: Does the above issue got fixed in any of recent Jedis updates ? If yes, is there any release notes regarding this jedis issue fix? Kindly help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is outlined in [this page](http://www.javaworld.com/article/3062899/big-data/lightning-fast-nosql-with-spring-data-redis.html?page=2). From the article:

> I learned a hard lesson when enabling Redis transactions in the Spring RedisTemplate class redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);: Redis started returning junk data after running for a few days, causing serious data corruption. A similar case was reported on StackOverflow.
>
> By running a monitor command, my team discovered that after a Redis operation or RedisCallback, Spring doesn't close the Redis connection automatically, as it should do. Reusing an unclosed connection may return junk data from an unexpected key in Redis. Interestingly, this issue doesn't show up when transaction support is set to false in RedisTemplate.
>
> We discovered that we could make Spring close Redis connections automatically by configuring a PlatformTransactionManager (such as DataSourceTransactionManager) in the Spring context, then using the @Transactional annotation to declare the scope of Redis transactions.
>
> Based on this experience, we believe it's good practice to configure two separate RedisTemplates in the Spring context: One with transaction set to false is used on most Redis operations; the other with transaction enabled is only applied to Redis transactions. Of course PlatformTransactionManager and @Transactional must be declared to prevent junk values from being returned.
>
> Moreover, we learned the downside of mixing a Redis transaction with a relational database transaction, in this case JDBC. Mixed transactions do not behave as you would expect.